# How to remove duplicates then map values in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a filter that receives data and then displays it. What I want to do is remove the duplicates from my data, however, I am not sure how I would do it in this case. I am using filter and map together, however, my label keys are not displayed. How can I both map the data in this case and show the label as well as filter the data to remove duplicates?

Here is my code filtering code:

```
 props.dataItem[props.field] = e.target.value
        .filter((element, index) => localizedData.indexOf(element) === index)
        .map((item) => {
          return item.label;
        })
        .join(',');
      props.onChange({
        dataIndex: 0,
        dataItem: props.dataItem,
        field: props.field,
        syntheticEvent: e.syntheticEvent,
        value: e.target.value,
        tabIndex: 0,
      });
    }
  };
  const localizedData = [
    { value: 'one', label: 'one', id: 1 },
    { value: 'two', label: 'two', id: 2 },
    { value: 'three', label: 'three', id: 3 },
    { value: 'four', label: 'four', id: 4 },
    { value: 'four', label: 'four', id: 4 },
  ];
```

And my entire code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { MultiSelect } from '@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns';

export const SymphonyMultiSelectCell = (props) => {
  let dataItemKey = 'value';
  let textField = 'label';

  const onChange = (e) => {
    if (props.onChange) {
      console.log('e.target.value...', e.target.value);
      let values = e.target.value;
      console.log(values);
      let arrayLength = values.length;
      let dataChangeDisplay = '';
      let fieldValues = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        if (i == arrayLength - 1) {
          dataChangeDisplay = dataChangeDisplay + values[i][dataItemKey];
        } else {
          dataChangeDisplay = dataChangeDisplay + values[i][dataItemKey] + ',';
        }
        fieldValues.push(values[i]);
        console.log('fieldValues', fieldValues);
      }

      props.dataItem[props.field] = e.target.value
        .filter((element, index) => localizedData.indexOf(element) === index)
        .map((item) => {
          return item.label;
        })
        .join(',');
      props.onChange({
        dataIndex: 0,
        dataItem: props.dataItem,
        field: props.field,
        syntheticEvent: e.syntheticEvent,
        value: e.target.value,
        tabIndex: 0,
      });
    }
  };
  const localizedData = [
    { value: 'one', label: 'one', id: 1 },
    { value: 'two', label: 'two', id: 2 },
    { value: 'three', label: 'three', id: 3 },
    { value: 'four', label: 'four', id: 4 },
    { value: 'four', label: 'four', id: 4 },
  ];
  return (
    <td>
      <MultiSelect
        data={localizedData}
        textField="value"
        dataItemKey="id"
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </td>
  );
};
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what the data is that you want to remove that duplicates of is. Please share an example of that data in your question, and how you want it to look after the duplicates have been removed.

Comment: You example is very confusing. Why are you updating the props? What is the actual data you want to remove duplicates from? Please read [mre] and make a **minimal** reproducible example. Just dumping all your code here and expecting people to take their time to go through it all and try to understand what you want is expecting a bit too much.

Comment: The data that I want to remove duplicates from is this:

 const localizedData = [
    { value: 'one', label: 'one', id: 1 },
    { value: 'two', label: 'two', id: 2 },
    { value: 'three', label: 'three', id: 3 },
    { value: 'four', label: 'four', id: 4 },
    { value: 'four', label: 'four', id: 4 },
  ];

and after the duplicates have been removed it should again be an array of objects

Comment: @super this is as minimal as it can be, it is obviously not just dumped code and I have clearly explained what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @Jordan please [edit] your question to include this so that it can be formatted correctly. Please share what you want as the result exactly, do you only want one of the objects with `id: 4` to be removed, or both? What are you wanting to deduplicate by, all properties `value`, `label` and `id`, or one of the properties just by `id`?

Comment: Will you still have this issue if you remove the duplicate object from `localizedData` mannually?

Comment: @Jordan This is not as minimal as it can be. It is also not clearly explained. What you have done is take the component that is not working, and copy-pasted all that code into here. Then explained in words what you want. What you should do is make a code example that isolates the specific issue you have and demostrate the actual result compared to the desired results. The quality of the answers are a direct indication of how clear you question is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove duplicates item in your arr, you can do it in one line:

```
const uniqueNames = Array.from(new Set(names));
```

Comment: Yes, but in this case I need to remove them from props.dataItem[props.field] = e.target.value and keep the return item.label logic so that I can display the values

Comment: Ok but you props.dataItem its arr beacasue you use map
 const arr = Array.from(new Set(props.dataItem));

Comment: How can I then pass the uniqueNames?

Comment: this is some name i gave,you can call it how ever you want

Comment: I know that, however, the solution that you provided does not work for my case.

Comment: This is the solutin, you just need to config it to your code. dont give up

Comment: I am not asking how to remove duplicates in general but how to do it in this specific case when I have to map and return the item.label

Comment: If you use map, ITS RETURN AN ARRAY.
After you get the array, you can use this array to remove what ever you want.

Comment: Creating a new `Set` will not remove duplicate objects.

Comment: @mstephen19 please provide some ref to this.

Comment: @yanirmidler just try it out for yourself. Two objects despite having the same exact properties will have different memory addresses, therefore being considered different.

Answer (score 0):

In your filtering logic, you currently are comparing ***object equality***.

What this means is that two different objects with the same properties are still considered ***distinct***.

eg:

```js
({ a: 1, b: 2 }) === ({ a: 1, b: 2 }) // returns false
```

Thus, your `filter` expression considers each item distinct as well:

eg:

```js
x = [ { a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 1, b: 2 } ]
x.filter((element, index) => x.indexOf(element) === index).length // Still is 2
```

You'll need to explicitly define what equality means in the context of your application between two of the objects for it to appropriately match and remove.